# list.files in R is not showing directories that contain a parenthesis

Tags: r

I am using list.files in R to create a list of all files inside a folder, including all subfolders:

```
files<-list.files(folder,recursive = T)
```

However, if there is a subfolder with a parenthesis "(" or ")" in its name, I don't get it on the list. Is there some way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work fine:

```
> list.files("C:/app/Folder1", full.names=TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
[1] "C:/app/Folder1/Folder(3)/inf3.txt" "C:/app/Folder1/Folder2/inf2.txt"   "C:/app/Folder1/inf1.txt"
```

Can you edit your OP with a reproducible example please?
(also more experienced users - this seemed too complex for a comment, but isn't truly an answer - should I remove it?)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `include.dirs = TRUE`

From the documentation:

> `include.dirs`
> logical. Should subdirectory names be included in recursive listings? (They always are in non-recursive ones)

(defaults to `FALSE`)

This seems to have nothing to do with parentheses in folder name.

Comment: You are right, looks like the problem was that there were some folders that didn't have any file inside, so they were only listed when using include.dirs=TRUE. They happened to be the same that had parenthesis on their names, so I assumed that was the problem. This is now solved, thank you!